# SQL Exception when debugging in vs code only (works in visual studio)

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-code

Im working on an existing .net project, so im getting it working locally.

It was built by people on windows OS (im not sure if that matters but it does seem to be an os problem maybe)

Im on mac osx.

When i launch the app via terminal `'dotnet run'` or through vs code. 
There seems to be an sql connection problem, as an exception occurs.

Through vscode the exception is:

```
An exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in System.Data.SqlClient.dll but was not handled in user code: 'A connection was successfully established with the server, but then an error occurred during the pre-login handshake. (provider: SSL Provider, error: 31 - Encryption(ssl/tls) handshake failed)'
 Inner exceptions found, see $exception in variables window for more details.
 Innermost exception     System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException : Error occurred during a cryptographic operation.
   at Internal.Cryptography.Pal.SecTrustChainPal.ParseResults(SafeX509ChainHandle chainHandle, X509RevocationMode revocationMode)
   at Internal.Cryptography.Pal.SecTrustChainPal.Execute(DateTime verificationTime, Boolean allowNetwork, OidCollection applicationPolicy, OidCollection certificatePolicy, X509RevocationFlag revocationFlag)
   at Internal.Cryptography.Pal.ChainPal.BuildChain(Boolean useMachineContext, ICertificatePal cert, X509Certificate2Collection extraStore, OidCollection applicationPolicy, OidCollection certificatePolicy, X509RevocationMode revocationMode, X509RevocationFlag revocationFlag, DateTime verificationTime, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Chain.Build(X509Certificate2 certificate, Boolean throwOnException)
   at System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Chain.Build(X509Certificate2 certificate)
   at System.Net.CertificateValidationPal.VerifyCertificateProperties(SafeDeleteContext securityContext, X509Chain chain, X509Certificate2 remoteCertificate, Boolean checkCertName, Boolean isServer, String hostName)
   at System.Net.Security.SecureChannel.VerifyRemoteCertificate(RemoteCertValidationCallback remoteCertValidationCallback, ProtocolToken& alertToken)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.CompleteHandshake(ProtocolToken& alertToken)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.CheckCompletionBeforeNextReceive(ProtocolToken message, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartSendBlob(Byte[] incoming, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.ProcessReceivedBlob(Byte[] buffer, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.ReadFrameCallback(AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.InternalEndProcessAuthentication(LazyAsyncResult lazyResult)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.EndProcessAuthentication(IAsyncResult result)
   at System.Net.Security.SslStream.EndAuthenticateAsClient(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskFactory`1.FromAsyncCoreLogic(IAsyncResult iar, Func`2 endFunction, Action`1 endAction, Task`1 promise, Boolean requiresSynchronization)
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SNI.SNITCPHandle.EnableSsl(UInt32 options)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SNI.SNIProxy.EnableSsl(SNIHandle handle, UInt32 options)
```

Through terminal (dotnet run):

```
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.ExceptionHandlerMiddleware[1]
An unhandled exception has occurred while executing the request.
System.InvalidOperationException: The ConnectionString property has not been initialized.
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.PermissionDemand()
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.PermissionDemand(DbConnection outerConnection)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.TryOpenConnectionInternal(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.TryOpenConnection(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpen(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open()
```

But if i run via visual studio for mac (not vs code) it works fine..?
Also i noticed that it would only run on visual studio for mac when i upgraded the project to 2.1+

What is going on here?

Comment: Check the accepted answer for this [SO question - Error occurred during the pre-login handshake](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43597294/error-occurred-during-the-pre-login-handshake). The accepted answer involved increasing the timeout duration on the SQL Server database connection string.

Comment: i have to ask if you checked permissions for users and the type of user auth in the connection string

Comment: Would this matter if i can get it to run fine via visual studio for mac?

Comment: usually no i just like to check to verify access and limit the debug steps especcialy since the error are mentioning permissiondemand and certificates

Comment: and since it works on vs for mac only after you updated it to 2.1+ maybe some dependencies or packages need to be updated since vs works with sln files for nuget packages and sometimes keeps them in a different location than the terminal or vscode run witch use csproj files